# .NET FtpWebRequest NLST isn't listing directories - Yet LIST does

Tags: .net, ftp, ftpwebrequest

FTP Root Content:

```
My File 1.txt
Your File 2.txt
Random File 3.txt
Another Random File 4.txt
Folder1
Folder 2
My Folder 3
Your Folder 4
```

Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory results:

```
My File 1.txt
Your File 2.txt
Random File 3.txt
Another Random File 4.txt
```

WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails results:

```
drwxrwxrwx   1 user     group           0 Mar 22 11:32 Folder1
drwxrwxrwx   1 user     group           0 Mar 22 11:33 Folder 2
drwxrwxrwx   1 user     group           0 Mar 22 11:33 My Folder 3
drwxrwxrwx   1 user     group           0 Mar 22 11:33 Your Folder 4
-rw-rw-rw-   1 user     group    234003230 Mar 22 14:12 My File 1.txt
-rw-rw-rw-   1 user     group    234003230 Mar 22 14:12 Your File 2.txt
-rw-rw-rw-   1 user     group    234003230 Mar 22 14:12 Random File 3.txt
-rw-rw-rw-   1 user     group    234003230 Mar 22 14:12 Another Random File 4.txt
```

Normally the `NSLT` provides me with a list of everything (including the folders).

The `NLST` gives me just the folder/file names which makes it convenient for sub-stringing out the date, file size, etc from the `LIST` results.

I can provide code samples. However this appears to be maybe an FTP setting. Just not sure where to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed some FTP servers do include files only in the `NLST` listing, for example HPUX `ftpd`.

The reason is that the `NLST` is used by command-line `ftp` clients to implement the `mget` command. A typical `mget` implementation cannot download files recursively (it actually has no way to tell if a particular "name" is a directory or a file). So the `mget` fails, if it gets a directory in the listing.

While the behavior may be configurable on the server-side, there's no standard way you can control this on a client-side.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Much appreciated.